# How to escape colon (:) using NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

We're trying to execute a set of SQL commands; however, the colon (:) keeps getting interpreted as a parameter placeholder. It is possible to escape a colon (:) while executing literal SQL using the CreateSQLQuery() method in NHibernate?

I've looked in the documentation for Java's Hibernate and there some ways to escape the symbol; but I'm haven't been able to find similar information for NHibernate.

Comment: have you tryed :: or \:?

Comment: @peer Tried both. Neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the NHibernate documentation and some reported Jira issues, escaping a `:` is not currently supported.